# Calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x} \sin{(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})}$

Tags: limits, analysis

How to calculate $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x} \sin{(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})} $?

I tried putting $\sqrt{x}$ in denominator and using de l'Hospital theorem, but 0/0 expressions don't disappear. According to WolframAlpha it should be convergent to 1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and considering $t\to 0^+$ you get

\begin{eqnarray*} \sqrt{x} \sin{(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})}
& \stackrel{x=\frac 1t}{=} & \frac{\sin \frac{\sqrt{1+t}-1}{\sqrt{t}}}{\sqrt{t}} \\
& = & \frac{\sin \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{1+t}+1}}{\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{1+t}+1}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}+1} \\
& \stackrel{t\to 0^+}{\rightarrow} & \frac{1}{2} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

Write your term in the form
$$\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$$